# Show step-by-step dialogs for helping user with using the site

Tags: 7, users, workflows, forms

I built an app with Drupal, and I would like to add step-by-step dialogs to help users learn how to use the app.

I found some boostrap plugins, but I would like to know if there is already a Drupal module that has this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modules chrischarlton suggested were fine, but those are unsupported and not maintained.

I recommend using the [Boostrap tour](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap_tour) module. With this module, you can show popups step-by-step, attach the popups to HTML elements in each step, save the progress of the user, and let the user add feedback to the tour. However, you need to have a boostrap based theme in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Here's the relevant modules you'll want to review. Pick the one that fits your exact use case, and let us know how it works out for your site:

1. **Guided Tours** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/guided_tours
2. **Guidance** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/guidance

One other module that comes to mind is **Tutorials** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/tutorials - this one allows you to embed help videos, so it's different but you may find it useful on your site.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there are a couple other JQuery integrated projects:

- [Page Guide](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_guide)
- [Joyride](https://www.drupal.org/project/joyride)

Also note that [a Joyride-based tour is included in Drupal 8 core](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/tour)!